# Python subprocess PIPE that works on Python 2 but not on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to control a software MIDI synthesizer [Timidity++](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/) with subprocess in Python.  The way I'm doing it is to start a process of Timidity++ in its Ncurses UI, and then pass commands to the STDIN of the subprocess.  This way I can control the playback, for example adjust keys, in real-time.

The problem is that the approach seems to work on Python 2 (specifically Python 2.7.13), but not on Python 3 (specifically Python 3.5.3).  What's the reason for that?  I'm testing this on Raspbian 9.

My code is like the following:

```
from subprocess import *
import time
a = Popen(["timidity", "-in", "MIDI_sample.mid"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"+")
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"s")
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"s")
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"q")
```

This seems to work well on Python 2, i.e you can hear the playback, pause and unpause, and key adjustments.  On Python 3 it just plays through the MIDI file until the program terminates.

Comment: I suspect it is the different between string vs bytes vs unicode, but can't place it.

Comment: That's what I suspected in the first place.  But I'm using `b"..."` literals which should give me bytes in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Does flushing `a.stdin` help?

Comment: It does!  Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Davis pointed out in the above comment, flushing `a.stdin` solved the problem.  So the following code works for both Python 2 and 3:

```
from subprocess import *
import time
a = Popen(["timidity", "-in", "MIDI_sample.mid"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"+")
a.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"s")
a.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"s")
a.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(4)
a.stdin.write(b"q")
a.stdin.flush()
```